# xmlhttp request onreadystatechange return value sent to an array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

xmlhttp request returns a different numerical value everytime. I want to call it every 2 seconds upto 10 times and send those values into an array.

I tried below approach.Its not working

```
function dif() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
var returned = (new Date).getTime();
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var timestamp = request.responseText.split('|');
    var original = + timestamp[0];
    var receive = + timestamp[1];
    var timeoffset = original - receive;
    return timeoffset

}
}
request.open("POST", "sync.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("original=" + (new Date).getTime());

}


var times = [];

function time() {
times.push(dif());
if (times.length < 10) {
    setTimeout(time, 2000);
}
}

setTimeout(time, 100);
```

Please advice me how can i put those values into an array times=[]

Comment: Hint 1: Your Ajax is asynchronous. (Hint 2: your `dif()` function doesn't have a `return` statement, but really you don't want to try to return a value from there because that would only work if you changed the Ajax to be synchronous and that's a bad plan. You should restructure the code a bit such that the `times.push()` happens inside the `onreadystatechange` callback.)

Comment: Just change `return timeoffset` to `times.push(timeoffset)`, since your `times` array is an _evil_ global var

Comment: ... and replace `times.push(dif());` by just `dif();`. Additionally you will have to remove both the `setTimeout()` calls and place a new call like `setTimeout(dif, 2000);` at the end of the `onreadystatechange` callback